# help understand mvc php

Tags: php, model-view-controller

ok yesterday i open a thread about when to use mvc,

today I'm about to learn how MVC frameworks work, examining some examples like CI, CAKE, etc

1. on the .htaccess i found this

   RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?url=$1 [QSA,L]

ok so when we type http://localhost/mymvc/something1/something2/something3/somethingetc

we got an `$_GET['url']  =`string 'something1/something2/something3/somethingetc' (length=45)

2.so I suggest the something1 will be the class, something2 must be the function and something3 im not quite sure,  how does exectly framework loads the class ?, functions ?

```
class Blog extends Controller {

    function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
    function stack()
    {
        echo 'Hello Stack!';
    }      
}
```

3.ok so , i found that every framework first loads the config files, then loads a front-controller this is a front-controller ( on ci ) looks, i assume that they do like this ?

> - extends the class ?
> - they get the name of the class ? then require_once controller.nameclass.php
> - then they somehow search for functions ? ( how do they do that ? )
> - next they look for the default function ( function index ) then loads it ?
> - if there is a client call the url /Blog/stack it loads just the Stack function, i dont >know how that work either .
> - if we put $this->loadview('something') so i assume that they call the function loadview ( that is inside the Controller class and require them by the name, like require_once something.php

Maybe there is a part two of this :|,

Thanks a lot.

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: You could just open up the source code for your chosen framework in an editor and find out how it works =)

Comment: yup im doing that right now, still no clue how it works. btw thanks for looking in :)

Comment: [Front Controller is not MVC](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html). It's common to have one when using webbased MVC, but it's still a separate pattern. MVC splits user interface interaction into three distinct roles. The most important aspect of it is separating the application logic from the presentation layer. If you want to understand MVC, do not look at concrete framework implementations but [read about the MVC pattern as such](http://books.google.de/books?id=FyWZt5DdvFkC&lpg=PA1&dq=web%20presentational%20patterns&pg=PT357#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The framework that built this .htaccess file, uses PHP to decompose its elements (possibly slower than Apache would do it with more complex declarations in .htaccess)
2. Yes, it determines the class (Controller) and the method to call (Action), and passes the rest of the parameters to that method. It uses `call_user_func` or something similar to call the functionality after the framework's core functionality has executed.
3. A function presence can be checked also. PHP has some basic Reflection implementation, which allows you to see what the class/object is built of.

Controller classes in many cases inherit a base class, for this functionality.

This doesn't really give you much. You'd have better luck with the frameworks if you learn how to work with it, not how it works.

It might help if you take a course of pure MVC (not linked to any framework), or if you're in a hurry, try [this](http://alexandermp.com/post/2010/06/30/MVC-Model-View-Controller-description.aspx).

Comment: for number one, well there are some framework ( vanilla2 ) who does not decompose its elemets by doing that in .htacses, but how do they parse a $_GET ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question. If .htaccess passes on the requested URL after the domain name as a string in $_GET, it can be easily decomposed using the `explode` method in PHP.
If "beautiful" URLs are present, on Apache, there must be a rewrite condition in .htaccess to do that.

Comment: you got that right. oh i see, so they explode it to array ? then they search the first array ( class ) second array ( function ) ? is that faster then above ? thanks

Comment: In general, there are more ways of handling this: 1. Write regular expressions in .htaccess that would separate the controller, action and parameters from the URL, so PHP would only work with many $_GET parameters. 2. Use .htaccess only to pass the URL as a $_GET parameter to PHP, and let PHP with explode function do the rest - take the first parameter as controller name, second as action name, etc. 3. Same as above, but use regular expressions instead of explode; this is slower, but can handle more complex URL composition techniques.

Comment: great, anyway the call_user_func is a very very useful to me thanks, maybe i should wait for others :)

Comment: There are much more wonderful features in PHP that you should know about.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.classobj.php
look through them. You will find many interesting and useful stuff. Oh, and also check out PHP Magic Methods - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simplified example: http://r.je/mvc-in-php.html

Comment: don't post just plain links otherwise your answer is worthless if the link breaks!